# why the current date do not update

Tags: plugins, query

I'm using the following query to update fields in my table if token is matching, but the current date is not getting inserted

```
$this->wpdb->update(  
            'wp_competitors',  
            array(  
                'results' => $tips,  // json  
                'update_time' => ' CURDATE()' //  
            ),  
            array( 'token' => $token ),  
            array(  
                '%s',   // value1  
                '%d'    // value2  
            ),  
            array( '%d' )  
        );
```

than I was trying to use php's date('Y-m-d H:i:s') but no results

Answer (score 0):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows):

```
<?php $wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null ); ?>
```

In your exampe ' CURDATE()' is simply a string, not a MySQL function (or something else).

The correct syntax for php's [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is:

```
date( [format], [timestamp] )
```

Try this:

```
$this->wpdb->update(  
            'wp_competitors',  
            array(  
                'results' => $tips,  // json  
                'update_time' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() )
            ),  
            array( 'token' => $token ),  
            array(  
                '%s',   // value1  
                '%d'    // value2  
            ),  
            array( '%d' )  
        );
```

Better than php's date() is WordPress [current_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time):

```
current_time( 'mysql' )
```

This will return something similiar to `2012-12-02 23:00:08`